# boost::asio::io_service to retrieve data in main

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Come across the following codes (from user368831) which is what I am looking for. I have modified a little to make it a threaded TCP session that listen and read for connection and data while the main loop can do other tasks.

```
class CSession
{
public:
    CSession(boost::asio::io_service& io_service) : m_Socket(io_service)
    {}

    tcp::socket& socket() return m_Socket;

    void start()
    {
        boost::asio::async_read_until(m_Socket, m_Buffer, " ",
                                      boost::bind(&CSession::handle_read, this,
                                      boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                                      boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
    }

    void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
                     size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            ostringstream ss;
            ss << &m_Buffer;
            m_RecvMsg = ss.str();
            std::cout << "handle_read():" << m_RecvMsg << std::endl;
        }
        else
            delete this;
    }    

private:
    boost::asio::streambuf  m_Buffer;
    tcp::socket             m_Socket;
    string                  m_RecvMsg;
};

class CTcpServer
{
public:
    CTcpServer(short port)
    : m_Acceptor(m_IOService, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port)),
    m_Thread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &m_IOService))
    {        
        CSession* new_session = new CSession(m_IOService);

        m_Acceptor.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
                                boost::bind(&CTcpServer::handle_accept, this, new_session,
                                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    };

    void handle_accept(CSession* new_session, const boost::system::error_code& error) 
    {
        if (!error)
        {
             new_session->start();
             new_session = new CSession(m_IOService);
             m_Acceptor.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
             boost::bind(&CTcpServer::handle_accept, this, new_session,
                            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
         }
         else
             delete new_session;
     }

private:
    boost::asio::io_service m_IOService;
    tcp::acceptor           m_Acceptor;
    boost::thread           m_Thread;

};

void main()
{
      :
    CTcpServer *server = new CTcpServer(6002); // tcp port 6002
    /* How to get the incoming data sent from the client here?? */
    // string message;
    // while(1)
    // {
    //    if ( server->incomingData(message) )
    //    {
    //      std::cout << "Data recv: " << message.data() << std::endl;
    //    }
    //      :
    //      : // other tasks
    //      :
    // } 
}
```

However, how do I code incomingData() in the main loop such that it will monitor the data from the client and return true whenever handle_read() is called?

Can use Boost::signals library in this case?

Comment: Check if post function of asio is of any use to you

Comment: Is placing the server into an own thread an option?

Answer (score 1):

This code is frankly horrible. There are memory leaks galore because of the way you are using raw pointers. Asio works best with `shared_ptr`s, it needs guarantees about the lifetimes of objects. I suggest you throw this code away, and start by looking at asio's simple enough to follow examples.

As for the method you want to code - that's not the way it works, you should put that logic in `handle_read`. `handle_read` will get called when you have a full message according to your protocol, you should put the logic you want to happen in this method - not in the main while loop. In your main thread, you should simply call `io_service::run()`.

Comment: Thanks Nim! In fact the above code is similar the Boost C++ ASIO example given in its website (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp). So I should use shared_ptr. Also, the io_service::run() is done in the CTcpServer constructor.

Comment: @tanlcc, yeah but it's dispatching in a different thread. Your main thread runs the while loop, if you want the two to interact, you need some form of queue (and sychronization mechanism) between the two...